# Textbook Example Replication gets an error

Tags: r

The book I am reading is Introduction to Statistical Learning by Witten. In chapter 8 where they are discussing Decision Tree, they have the following example:

```
library(ISLR)
library(tree)
attach(Carseats)
High = ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")
Carseats = data.frame(Carseats, High)
tree.carseats = tree(High ~. -Sales, Carseats)
summary(tree.carseats)
```

When I attempted to replicate this code, I get the following error:

> Error in y - frame$yval[object$where]: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Could someone explain why I am getting this message and how to fix it?

Comment: Good day Min, I when I added install.packages('ISLR') and install.packages('tree') it made the code run fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm so confused then. Did you just copy paste this code?

Comment: yes, I just copied and pasted the code and got errors for not having the packages installed. When I added the install.package() the code ran fine.

Comment: @Patrick25 Are you using a version of R < 4.0? I'm guessing that when you make the data.frame you are converting the character to a factor. In newer versions of R this does not happen automatically anymore.

Comment: I tried converting High into factor but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `?tree` help page, your response variable should be a numeric or a factor. You are passing a character vector. Some functions auto convert characters to factors but not this one apparently. You can do the conversion yourself with

```
High = factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes"))
```

I would also strongly discourage your from using `attach()`. It can lead to messy environment problems if you forget to `detach()`. Also it's better to return a new variable rather than shadowing a built in variable. This might be better

```
mycarseats <- transform(Carseats, High = factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes"))
tree.carseats <- tree(High ~. -Sales, mycarseats)
summary(tree.carseats)
Classification tree:
# tree(formula = High ~ . - Sales, data = mycarseats)
# Variables actually used in tree construction:
# [1] "ShelveLoc"   "Price"       "Income"      "CompPrice"  
# [5] "Population"  "Advertising" "Age"         "US"         
# Number of terminal nodes:  27 
# Residual mean deviance:  0.4575 = 170.7 / 373 
# Misclassification error rate: 0.09 = 36 / 400
```

Comment: hi, it still doesn't work. I'm getting the same error message

Comment: What does `sapply(Carseats, class)` return? Is the "High" column a factor? Did you re-run the `data.frame()` step?

Comment: Ah I removed Carseat and re-run the code. Now it's working! I tried changing High into factor before asking the question as well but it didn't work, so I thought I was wrong. When I rerun data.frame() function, it just creates a new High variable in the dataframe instead of overwriting the original High variable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's one of the problems of trying to reuse built in variable names with `attach()` and `data.frame`. It's safer and easier to use functions like `transform()`.